# Finding external usages using `Find Usages` command?

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to configure PyCharm to detect external usages of a function using `Find Usages` command? More specifically I have a project with following structure

```
foo/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    ...
  examples/
    example1.py
    example2.py
```

example1.py would have something like this

```
import foo
foo.run()
```

PyCharm correctly validates `foo.run` since the package is present in the environment associated with project (installed using `cd foo; pip install -e .`), but it doesn't detect usages of `foo.run` in my `examples` folder using `Find Usages` command on the `run` function under `foo/foo`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `run` is defined in `foo/foo.py` I see an undefined reference warning on `foo.run()` in `example1.py` (possibly explained by not doing a `pip install` for `foo`, not sure).

In this case I can, indeed, see the `Find usages` not finding it in `example1.py`.

But if I change the `example1.py` import to `from foo import foo` (which IMHO is more correct - `run` is part of module `foo.py` from package `foo` - should work regardless of doing a `pip install` or not) then the undefined reference warning goes away and `Find usages` correctly finds the `example1.py` usage. Give it a try.